# Best way to compare two signals in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compare, signal-processing, similarity

I have a signal I made in matlab that I want to compare to another signal (call them y and z).  What I am looking for is a way to assign a value or percentage of how similar two signals are.

I was trying to use corrcoef, but I get very poor values (`corrcoef(y,z) = -0.1141`), yet when I look at the FFT of the two plots superimposed on each other, I would have visually said that they are **very** similar.  Taking a look at the corrcoef of the FFT of the magnitude of the two signals looks a lot more promising: `corrcoef(abs(fft(y)),abs(fft(z))) = 0.9955`, but I am not sure if that is the best way to go about it since the two signals in their pure form appear to not be correlated.

Does anyone have a recommendation of how to compare two signals in Matlab as described?

Thanks!

Comment: A better place for this question is dsp.stackoverflow.com. (I tried flagging it to be moved, but, for some reason that site was not an option.)

Comment: Is there a dsp.stackoverflow?

Comment: sorry dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9):

The question is impossible to answer without a clearer definition of what you mean by "similar".

If by "similar" you mean "correlated frequency responses", then, well, you're one step ahead of the game!

In general, defining the proper metric is highly application specific; you need to answer *why* you want to know how similar these two signals are to know how to measure how similar they are.  Will they be input to the same system?  Do they need to be detected by the same algorithm?

In the meantime, your idea to use the freq-domain correlation is not bad.  But you might also consider

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

Or the likelihood of the time-series under various statistical models:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model

Or any number of other models...

I should add: In general, the correlation coefficient between two time-series is a very poor metric of the time-series' similarity, except under very specific circumstances (e.g., no shifts in phase)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I wasn't as clear as I had hoped to be, sorry. What I ultimately wanted to do was to take my original signal "mix" it down, so some stuff to it, "mix" it back up and see how close it was to the original signal. I knew it would be a little different since I had a LPF and BPF after the two mixings, so I wanted to rate how similar it was. Sadly, I am not sure that I cleared that up much, did I?

Comment: Dont be sorry.  You asked what you thought was a reasonable question.  Now you've got the fun stuff ahead of you!

Answer (score 7):

Pete is right that you need to define a notion of similarity before progressing further. You might find normalized maximum cross-correlation magnitude to be useful notion of similarity for your circumstances, however:

```
norm_max_xcorr_mag = @(x,y)(max(abs(xcorr(x,y)))/(norm(x,2)*norm(y,2)));
x = randn(1, 200); y = randn(1, 200); % two random signals 
norm_max_xcorr_mag(x,y)

ans = 0.1636

y = [zeros(1, 30), 3.*x]; % y is delayed, multiplied version of x
norm_max_xcorr_mag(x,y)

ans = 1
```

This notion of similarity is similar to rote correlation of the two sequences but is invariant to time delay.